# Memory overhead in JSF render response- ajax request

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, jboss, facelets

I'm using JSF 2.0 ,primefaces 3.3 and javax.faces-2.1.4.jar. i facing performance issues specially a memory overhead in renderresponse phase. even signle ajax request consumes lot of memory.

i'm maintening around 3000 components(panels , tabs, tables... etc) in the view tree and i'm trying to process and render only one panel which has only one text field. but it consumes more memory(**around 20MB**) for rendering. why is this starge behaviour happening ?

Can any one suggest to overcome this.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You have to be more specific. It is known the JSF implementation and version are related and some specific versions of Mojarra for example could have some bugs that has an effect over performance.

Comment: i'm currently using "javax.faces-2.1.4.jar". will it cause the performance issue.

Comment: That's too old, it is known some Mojarra versions has a bug that decrease performance on large component trees. See this article for details on [Blog oio de](http://blog.oio.de/2013/05/16/jsf-performance-mojarra-improves-dramatically-with-latest-release/). Use the newest one or try to switch to [Apache MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org) to get the best performance. Take a look at this article [Understading JSF 2.0 Performance Part 3](http://content.jsfcentral.com/c/journal/view_article_content?cmd=view&groupId=35702&articleId=73398&version=1.8) for details. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event during the Partial Request complete JSF view tree traversal happens.

The Solution,  which solved my issue is Reduce the number components in the View(Create multiple views with limited components), Add Dialogs to the corresponding view(Add dynamically), Removing unwanted tab sources/Components from the view tree.

Answer (score 0):

You could use partial submits and partial updates if you are not already using them anyway ;)
Process what you really need to be processed in the ajax request and then update what u really need to be updated by the ajax response.

Comment: i have implemented in the same way :) . i hope the entire view tree got processed some how. i would like to avoid that one.